# How to add checkbox and image to JList

Tags: java, swing, jlist, listselectionlistener

The following code displays images MRI images in a JList. I want to add a checkbox with each image so the user can chose as many images they want and then perform calculations on all the images. I just can't seem to add a checkbox to the image. I have tried

```
list.setCellRenderer(new CheckBoxListRenderer);
```

but it doesn't recognize the checkboxlistrenderer. Does anybody know how I would go about doing this?

```
   DefaultListModel<ImageIcon> model = new DefaultListModel<ImageIcon>();
      JCheckBox check;
      int counter = 0;
      for(int i =0; i< image.getStackSize(); i++){
          image.setSliceWithoutUpdate(i);
          ImageIcon c = new ImageIcon();
          c.setImage(image.getBufferedImage());
          model.addElement(c);
          counter++;
        }
        final int finalCounter = counter;

        image.setPosition(1);
        JList<ImageIcon> list = new JList<ImageIcon>(model);

        list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener(){

            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(arg0.getValueIsAdjusting() ==false)
                    return;

                JList l = (JList) arg0.getSource();

                if(l.isSelectionEmpty())
                    System.out.println("List is empty!");

                int index = ((JList)arg0.getSource()).getSelectedIndex();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append("Image #: ");

                for(int i =0; i< image.getStackSize();i++){
                    if(index == i){
                        sb.append(i+1);
                        sb.append("/");
                        sb.append(finalCounter);
                        String strI = sb.toString();
                        txt.setText(strI);
                        image.setSlice(i);
                        frame.setImage(image);
                    }
                }

            }



        });


        JScrollPane listScroll = new JScrollPane(list,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

        JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, listScroll, panel2);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't recognize"? What's the error?

Comment: If the check-box were filled according to selection of multiple list items it becomes quite simple.  Otherwise I'd suggest maybe a `JTable` or a `JList` item (Object instance) that stores both the image and a `boolean` value for `analyze`..

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: @JanEglinger the error is that CheckBoxListRenderer cannot be resolved to a type. So I built the class and it displays the checkboxes but not the images. I can't seem to figure out how to display the images alongside with the checkboxes.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I tried a JTables as well but when I do that nothing seems to appear. Like theres no checkbox or image displayed.

Comment: Well like I mentioned on July 1, (for better help sooner) post an MCVE.